# Thread 1: Fatal error: Expected superview but found nil when attempting make constraint `equalToSuperview`

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I would like to designate the constant print of tableview cell. However, the following error occurs: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Expected superview but found nil when attempting make constraint `equalToSuperview`." What error is this and how can it be solved?

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        addSubview(profleImage)
        addSubview(nameLbl)
        addSubview(timeLbl)
        addSubview(titleTxtField)
        addSubview(contentTxtView)
        addSubview(postImage)
        addSubview(sirenLbl)
        addSubview(sirenBtn)
        
        profleImage.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            $0.top.equalTo(snp.top).offset(15)
            $0.width.height.equalTo(50)
            $0.leading.equalTo(20)
        }
        nameLbl.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            $0.top.equalTo(snp.top).offset(15)
            $0.leading.equalTo(profleImage.snp.trailing).offset(15)
        }
        timeLbl.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(nameLbl.snp.bottom).offset(5)
            $0.leading.equalTo(profleImage.snp.trailing).offset(15)
        }
        titleTxtField.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(profleImage.snp.bottom).offset(25)
            $0.leading.equalTo(30)
            $0.trailing.equalTo(-30)
        }
        contentTxtView.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(titleTxtField.snp.bottom).offset(18)
            $0.leading.equalTo(30)
            $0.trailing.equalTo(-30)
        }
        postImage.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(contentTxtView.snp.bottom).offset(18)
            $0.leading.equalTo(30)
            $0.trailing.equalTo(-30)
        }
        sirenLbl.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.top.equalTo(postImage.snp.bottom).offset(23)
            $0.leading.equalTo(30)
        }
        sirenBtn.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.leading.equalTo(sirenLbl.snp.trailing).offset(10)
            $0.top.equalTo(postImage.snp.bottom).offset(23)
        }
        moreBtn.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.centerX.equalToSuperview()
            $0.trailing.equalTo(-10)
            $0.leading.equalTo(timeLbl.snp.trailing).offset(30)
        }
    }
```

This is my cell code.

Comment: You haven’t added your moreBtn as a subview.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this error.